# Filter Products on Create Sales Order

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to extend our standard fiori app - create sales order. On the products list, I would like to show only products that are available to the chosen customer. Right now all products are being displayed.

I tried just adding a filter on the view controller.

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2009-2014 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved
 */
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseMasterController");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.IconPool");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.odata.Filter");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ca.ui.CustomerContext");
jQuery.sap.require("cus.sd.salesorder.create.util.ModelUtils");
jQuery.sap.require("cus.sd.salesorder.create.util.Utils");

sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseMasterController.extend("cus.sd.salesorder.create.view.S2",
{
    onInit : function() {
        sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseMasterController.prototype.onInit.call(this);
        this.isSalesOrder = true;
        this.setDefaultSelection = false;
        this.customerEvent = 0;
        this.sFilterPattern = "";
        this.lock = false;

        this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        this.initializeValues();

        this.getList().attachUpdateStarted({}, this.onListUpdateStarted, this);
        this.getList().attachUpdateFinished({}, this.onListUpdateFinished, this);
        //this.getView().getModel().bCountSupported=true;     // FIXME: Enable expensive calls for count to make SalesOrder growing list

        //fix for customer pop up... review if framework resolves the close dialog issue.
        this.getView().addEventDelegate({
            onAfterShow : jQuery.proxy(this.onShow, this)
        });

    },

    onShow:function() {
        var oCartModel = this.oApplicationFacade.getApplicationModel("soc_cart");
        if(! oCartModel   || !oCartModel.getData().CustomerName)
        {
            this._setCustomerControl();
        }
    },

    onListUpdateStarted : function() {
            this.getView().byId("list").setNoDataText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("LOADING"));
    },

    onListUpdateFinished : function(){
            this.getView().byId("list").setNoDataText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("NO_ITEMS_AVAILABLE"));
    },


    onRequestCompleted : function() {
//        this.getView().getModel().detachRequestCompleted(jQuery.proxy(this.onRequestCompleted, this));
        this.lock = false;

        if(jQuery.device.is.phone) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.setDefaultSelection ) {
            this.setDefaultSelection = false;

            if (this.getList().getItems().length > 0) {
                if(this.isSalesOrder){
                    this.setListItem(this.getList().getItems()[1]);
                }
                else{
                    this.setListItem(this.getList().getItems()[0]);
                }
            } else {
                this.getView().byId("list").setNoDataText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("NO_ITEMS_AVAILABLE"));
                this.navToEmpty();
            }
        }
    },

    onNavToSalesOrders : function() {
        if(this.lock){
            return;
        }

        this.lock = true;

        this.isSalesOrder = true;
        this.updateCustomer();
    },

    onNavToProducts : function() {
        if(this.lock){
            return;
        }

        this.lock = true;

        this.isSalesOrder = false;
        this.updateCustomer();
    },

    updateCustomer : function(){
        var oCartModel = this.oApplicationFacade.getApplicationModel("soc_cart");

        if(oCartModel && oCartModel.getData()){
            this.oCustomerID = oCartModel.getData().CustomerNumber;
            this.oCustomerName = oCartModel.getData().CustomerName;
            this.oSalesOrganization = oCartModel.getData().SalesOrganization;
            this.oDivision = oCartModel.getData().Division;
            this.DistributionChannel = oCartModel.getData().DistributionChannel;
            this.CustName = oCartModel.getData().CustomerName;

            if(this.isSalesOrder){
                this.updateSalesOrdersList();
            }
            else{
                this.updateProductsList();
            }
        }
    },

    updateSalesOrdersList : function(){
        var filters = [];
        var sorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter('PO', false, this.oGroupPO);

        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrganization", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oSalesOrganization));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("DistributionChannel", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.DistributionChannel));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oCustomerID));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Division", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oDivision));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrderNumber", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, this.sFilterPattern));

        this.setDefaultSelection = true;

        this.getList().bindItems("/SalesOrders", new sap.ui.xmlfragment("cus.sd.salesorder.create.view.ListItemTemplate",this), sorter,filters);
        var sTitle = this.getView().byId("SOC_MasterListHeaderTitle");
        sTitle.setText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("MASTER_TITLE", [this.CustName]));
        this.registerMasterListBind(this.getList());
    },

    updateProductsList : function(){
        var filters = [];
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrganization", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oSalesOrganization));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("DistributionChannel", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.DistributionChannel));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("ProductID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, this.sFilterPattern));
        filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, this.sCustomerNo));
        this.setDefaultSelection = true;

        this.getList().bindItems("/Products", new sap.ui.xmlfragment("cus.sd.salesorder.create.view.ProductListItemTemplate",this), null,filters);
        var sTitle = this.getView().byId("SOC_MasterListHeaderTitle");
        sTitle.setText(this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("PRODUCTS_CUST", [this.CustName]));
        this.registerMasterListBind(this.getList());
    },

    oGroupPO : function(oContext) {
        return oContext.getProperty("PO"); // group by first letter of last
        // name
    },

    getHeaderFooterOptions : function() {
        if (jQuery.device.is.phone) {
            return {};
        }
        return {onBack: null};
    },

    //taken from wave 1 code base. few variables not required. after review if not reqd we can remove this method.
    initializeValues : function() {
        this.top = 30;          //Initialize top and skip values to retrieve the first set of records from the back-end
        this.skip = 0;
        this.searchSkip = 0;    //Skip value for paging in search mode

        this.firstTime = true;
        this.serverSearch = false;      //True when searching back-end
        this.clientSearch = false;      //True when searching client

        this.latestFetch = 0;           //Number of records last fetched
        this.latestSearchFetch = 0;     //Number of records last fetched in server search
    },

    setListItem : function(oItem) {
        if (oItem && oItem.getBindingContext()) {
            this.setDefaultSelection = false;
            var oList = this.getList();
            oList.removeSelections();
            oItem.setSelected(true);
            oList.setSelectedItem(oItem, true);

            if(this.isSalesOrder){
                this.oRouter.navTo(
                        "detail", 
                        {contextPath : oItem.getBindingContext().sPath.substr(1)},
                        !jQuery.device.is.phone
                );
            }
            else{
                this.oRouter.navTo(
                        "productdetail", 
                        {
                            customerID : this.oCustomerID,
                            productID : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("ProductID"),
                            salesOrganization : this.oSalesOrganization,
                            distributionChannel : this.DistributionChannel,
                            division : this.oDivision
                        }, 
                        !jQuery.device.is.phone
                );
            }
        }
    },

    navToEmpty : function() {
        if(this.isSalesOrder){
            this.oRouter.navTo(
                    "noData", 
                    {
                        viewTitle : "SALES_ORDER_DETAIL",
                        languageKey : "NO_ITEMS_AVAILABLE"
                    },
                    !jQuery.device.is.phone
                );
        } else {
            this.oRouter.navTo(
                    "noData", 
                    {
                        viewTitle : "PRODUCT_DETAIL",
                        languageKey : "NO_ITEMS_AVAILABLE"
                    },
                    !jQuery.device.is.phone
                );
        }
    },

    // Override onDataLoaded to prevent first item selection error
    onDataLoaded : function() {
        this.onRequestCompleted();
    },

    /**
     * @override
     *
     * @param {*} oItem
     * @param {*} sFilterPattern
     * @returns {*}
     */
    applySearchPatternToListItem : function(oItem, sFilterPattern) {
        // if there is no filter
        if (sFilterPattern === "") {
            // then return all objects
            return true;
        }

        // else if this is a group header
        if (!oItem.getBindingContext()) {
            return false;
        }

        // else delegate to parent implementation
        return sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.BaseMasterController.prototype.applySearchPatternToListItem
                .call(null, oItem, sFilterPattern);
    },

    isBackendSearch : function() {
        // FIXME implement this functionality once it is
        // possible to search on the backend
        // if we have all the data on the client, we will do a
        // front end search, otherwise we will do a backend search

//        if(!this.getList().getBindingInfo("items")) {
//            return false;
//        }
//
//
//        var growingThreshold = this.getList().getBinding("items").getLength();
//        return this.numberOfItems < growingThreshold;
          return true;
    },

    /**
     * This is overridden so we can apply the backend search.
     *
     * It is called from the framework and should not be called
     * directly.
     *
     * ListBinding needs to be updated with filter parameter ->
     * this will trigger a new oData get automatically, and also
     * does not support a custom query parameter
     *
     * @param {String} sFilterPattern
     *            the content of the search field
     * @param {Object} oBinding
     *            the context binding (model + path) of
     *            the list items to be modified.
     */
    applyBackendSearchPattern : function(sFilterPattern, oBinding) {

        this.sFilterPattern = sFilterPattern;
        var aFilters=[];

        if(this.isSalesOrder) {
            aFilters = [
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oCustomerID),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrderNumber", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sFilterPattern),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrganization", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oSalesOrganization),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("DistributionChannel", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.DistributionChannel),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("Division", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oDivision)
                    ];
        } else {
            aFilters = [
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("ProductID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sFilterPattern),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("SalesOrganization", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oSalesOrganization),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("DistributionChannel", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.DistributionChannel)
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.oCustomerNo),
                    ];
        }


        this.setDefaultSelection = true;

        oBinding.filter(aFilters, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
    },

//  /*
//   * End SO Search
//   */

    /*
     * Customer Control Integration
     */
    _setCustomerControl : function () {
         this.customerContext = new sap.ca.ui.CustomerContext({
                personalizationPageName: "SRA017_SD_SO_CR",
                showSalesArea:true,
                customerSelected:jQuery.proxy(this.onCustomerSelected, this),
                path: "/Customers"
         });

         this.customerContext.setModel(this.oApplicationFacade.getODataModel());

         this.customerContext.select();
    },

    //This is called when the customerContext button is clicked on the view
    //the change() method
    changeInCustomerContext: function () {
         this.setDefaultSelection = true;
         this.customerChanged = true;
         this.customerContext.change();
    },

    //This is called when a customer is selected in the customer context popup
    onCustomerSelected: function (oEvent) {
        this.setDefaultSelection = true;

        if(this.customerChanged)
        {
            this.customerChanged = false;
            this.customerNewParams = oEvent.getParameters();
            var that = this;
            // Launch the dialog

            sap.ca.ui.dialog.confirmation.open({
                question :  this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("CONFIRM_CLEAR_CART"),
                showNote :  false,
                title :     this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("CONFIRMATION"),
                confirmButtonLabel : this.oApplicationFacade.getResourceBundle().getText("YES")
            }, function(oResult) {
                if (oResult.isConfirmed) {
                    that.handleCustomerChange(that.customerNewParams);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.handleCustomerChange(oEvent.getParameters());
        }
    },

    handleCustomerChange : function(customerParams){
        //THIS LINE CLEARS THE SHOPPING CART
        cus.sd.salesorder.create.util.ModelUtils._setCartModel();

        var oCartModel = this.oApplicationFacade.getApplicationModel("soc_cart");
        oCartModel.getData().CustomerName = customerParams.CustomerName;
        oCartModel.getData().CustomerNumber = customerParams.CustomerID;
        oCartModel.getData().SalesOrganization = customerParams.SalesOrganization;
        oCartModel.getData().Division = customerParams.Division;
        oCartModel.getData().DistributionChannel = customerParams.DistributionChannel;
        oCartModel.getData().itemCount= 0;
        oCartModel.getData().SingleShipment = false;
        oCartModel.getData().PurchaseOrder = "";
        oCartModel.getData().NotesToReceiver = "";
        oCartModel.getData().ShippingInstructions = "";

        this.updateCustomer();

        //The rest of the code in this function is needed to get the currency.
        var sParameters = "(CustomerID='" + customerParams.CustomerID + "',"+
        "SalesOrganization='" + customerParams.SalesOrganization + "'," +
        "DistributionChannel='" + customerParams.DistributionChannel + "'," +
        "Division='" + customerParams.Division + "')";

        function fnSuccess(response) {
            var oCartMdl = sap.ca.scfld.md.app.Application.getImpl().getApplicationModel("soc_cart");
            oCartMdl.getData().Currency = response.Currency;
            oCartMdl.updateBindings();
        }

        function fnError(oError) {
            cus.sd.salesorder.create.util.Utils.dialogErrorMessage(oError.response);
        }

        this.oApplicationFacade.getODataModel().read("/Customers" + sParameters, null, null, true, fnSuccess, fnError);
    }

});
```

but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea that can help me. Thanks.

Comment: add your code snippet/ controller code to get complete idea

Comment: check while adding filters this.oSalesOrganization has some value or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the solution. We had to implement the filtering from the gateway service first before implementing the filtering on the frontend.

The above code works, we just needed to implement the gateway filtering.

Answer (score 0):

assign the variable to something else like `_this`

```
var  _this = this;
//then use _this. As the scope changes "this" value changes
filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("CustomerNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, _this.sCustomerNo));
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Still showing all the products

Comment: Can you add full controller